# C# unable to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.int32'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, combobox

I am getting the error `unable to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.int32'` when retrieving a `varchar` column that contains data and trying it to display it in a ComboBox.

Here is my code:

```
private void GetFinancialCatDeactivate(int active)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var Connect = new SqlConnection(connstr))
                {
                    Connect.Open();
                    using (var Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spParametresFinancesTb_GetCategories]", Connect))
                    {
                        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        Command.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = active;
                        SqlDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            string catlist = dr.GetString(0)

                            ComboBoxFinanceNameDeactivate.Items.Add(catlist);
                            ComboBoxFinanceNameDeactivate.Text = catlist;
                            ComboBoxFinanceDefaultNameEdit.Items.Add(catlist);
                            ComboBoxFinanceDefaultNameEdit.Text = catlist;                            

                        }
                        dr.Close();
                    }

                    Connect.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The code is executing a stored procedure which is here:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spParametresFinancesTb_GetCategories]
(
    @active numeric(1)
 )
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON
            BEGIN
                    select category
                    from dbo.PARAMETRES_FINANCES 
                    where active = @active;
                END;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH     
        SELECT
        ERROR_PROCEDURE () as ProcedureErreur,
        ERROR_MESSAGE () as MessageErreur,
        ERROR_LINE () as LigneErreur,
        ERROR_SEVERITY () as SeveriteErreur
    END CATCH
END;
```

The error is appearing here: `ComboBoxFinanceDefaultNameEdit.Text = catlist;` in the code-behind.

I find it very weird since the fist combobox is not displaying the error.

Here is how both comboboxes are made (XAML):

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxFinanceDefaultNameEdit" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxFinanceDefaultNameEdit_SelectionChanged"/>
```

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxFinanceNameDeactivate" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"/>
```

I tried changing the `ComboBoxFinanceDefaultNameEdit.Text = catlist;` to `ComboBoxFinanceDefaultNameEdit.SelectedItem= catlist;` but it dind't change a thing.

Any idea what is going on here?

I am on .Net Core 3.1.101

**EDIT**

I have updated the question to add more information about the problem.

**EDIT 2**

I have noticed that the problem is appearing mainly on comboboxes where I have implemented a selectionchanged event. Without this event, no error. Still investigating how to fix this.

**EDIT 3**

I would like to mention that the error is shown as a messagebox. When I debug, it doesn't throw an exception but rather a messagebox. However, the data is still displayed in the combobox. The combobox where this problem appears is the one where I have a selectionchange event

Comment: Are `ComboBoxFinanceNameDeactivate` and `ComboBoxFinanceDefaultNameEdit` both the same type?

Comment: Sorry, your description is confusing me.  First, some prelim questions.  What does your data reader look like (what are the SQL types you are querying)?  In particular, what is the type of the first (/zeroeth) item?  What are the types of your two "combo boxes" (and, in particular, what kind of app is this, meaning what are the fully qualified type names of the comboboxes)?  Your `catlist` variable is definitely a string (if that first assignment doesn't throw), and every thing that I've ever looked at that had a `Text` property, had it as a `string`, so your error msg & location make no sense

Comment: I have updated the question so as to add more information about the issue. This is a little bit odd, I am suspecting that I might be making a mistake somewhere but can't see where...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the @active parameter. You see you have defined it as `SqlDbType.VarChar`

```
 Command.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = active;
```

But in your stored procedure you have marked it as `@active numeric(1)`.

Comment: Actually, the problem is not there as I have been able to pass data like this before. Plus, the first combobox is not displaying this error. I am starting to wonder if this is bug from microsoft or not...

Comment: _"I am starting to wonder if this is bug from microsoft or not"_ -- I guarantee you that it's not.

Comment: Thank you for your unhelpful comment. I am a beginner in programming so this may sound like a silly question but I am not able to understand where the problem is. How can I get this error when the result of SP is a string and I am passing it to a combobox. For information, I didn't change a thing in my code, but now it is throwing ``unable to cast object of type 'system.decimal' to type 'system.int32'``